# Odd-dimensional matrix manipulation on quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-circuit

Just wondering if there is any work on dealing with odd-dimensional matrix, i.e. a matrix of which the dimension is N by N where N is an odd integer, and one could, for instance, solve the eigenproblem or perform SVD on it?

Comment: Pad it with extra rows and columns until it becomes a size that you know how to deal with.

Comment: yeah right but then very likely it won't be hermitian?

Comment: why not? If you add an equal number of all zero rows and columns to the end of the matrix, it will be Hermitian if your original matrix was Hermitian.

Comment: right. sorry originally I was thinking of an arbitrary matrix.